# Why do Perl's and Python's output of print with "\n" differ?

Tags: python, perl

Why do I need to put "\n" twice after "Content-Type: text/html" with Perl, but only once with Python? For example, the following Python script works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print "Hello World!"
```

But the following Perl script doesn't work (it gives a premature end of script headers error message):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-Type: text/html\n";
print "Hello World!";
```

Instead I need to add an extra "\n" to get it to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello World!";
```

Comment: -1: The answer is "Because they're different languages".  Why ask?  How can you sensibly compare two different languages?  If you're going to compare languages, why not ask about Ruby, C++, C# and VB, also?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because print in Python prints with a newline and print in Perl does not.

`print "Hello world!"` in Python is equivalent to `print "Hello world!\n"` in perl. Perl 6 has  a `say` command which does the same thing as Python's print, but sadly, Perl 6 has no stable implementations. In Perl 5.10 or later, you can use `say` by putting `use feature 'say'` in your script.

Answer (score 10):

Perl's [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) doesn't add a newline. Perl's [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) does. These are equivalent:

```
# Python
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print ""
print "Hello World!"

# Perl
print "Content-Type: text/html\n";
print "\n";
print "Hello World!\n";

# Perl
local $\ = "\n";
print "Content-Type: text/html";
print "";
print "Hello World!";

# Perl
use 5.010;
say "Content-Type: text/html";
say "";
say "Hello World!";
```

I recommend not touching `$\`; it can too easily affect code you don't want it to affect.

Answer (score 1):

Python's `print` outputs a newline automatically; Perl's doesn't (unless you set `$\ = "\n"`).  With newer Perl there's also `say`, as mentioned by others.